# Make parent div with absolute position take the width of children divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following html structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

The parent is positioned absolutely, child1 and child2 are displayed side-by-side using inline-block.
I need this whole thing to be responsive based on the width of the 2 children divs. the problem is, if I increase the width of any of them, the parent's width remains the same. Changing its position to relative fixes this, but I have to have it in absolute.
Is there anyway to get it to be responsive?

**EDIT:**

I was hoping for this to be simple, but apparently not so much... :(
here's the actual HTML:

```
<div class="action_container">
    <div class="action_inner">
        <div class="action_title">Format Text</div>
        <div class="action_body">
            <div class="action_args_section"></div>
            <div class="action_output_section"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
<style>
    .action_container {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .action_inner {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    .action_inner {
        min-width: 120px;
        min-height: 50px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .action_title {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .action_args_section {
        display: inline-block;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 3px;
    }

    .action_output_section {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        vertical-align: top;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 3px;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: could you post your CSS too.....need to look at what styles you already defined on each of those divs....

Comment: Can you see the slyles that is applied on each divs using inspect elements? Otherwise you have to give us some fiddles to work on.

Comment: Based on the code update, I'm not sure what you're looking for. Do you want the box to resize as the _window_ resizes? Or do you just want the parent div to fit the width of the child divs? Because that and "responsive" mean two different things.

Comment: action_inner has to take the width of both divs inside the action_body. Right now this happens only if I take the position: relative off of action_container...

Answer (score 7):

```
.parent{

  position: absolute;
  display: table;

}

.child{

  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;

}
```

Use this trick to set children in single line and parent to get width from them. Don't apply floats to nothing. And remember about *white-space: nowrap;* if You need to keep single line in child elements.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/3/).

Answer (score 3):

```css
.parent {
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.child1 {
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid green;
}
.child2 {
    width:150px;
    height:30px;
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aywmn3zt/)

Comment: This sets the explicit child width, you have to avoid that and try to solve it.

Comment: @Lance that requirement was added after this answer. also, this answer is almost a decade old.

Answer (score 0):

see the sample solution here in jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wpces4wb/)

using this css:

```
.parent{
    position:fixed;
    background-color:blue;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
.child1{width:200px;background-color:black;height:200px;float:left;}
.child2{width:200px;background-color:red;height:200px; float:left;}
```

if it is not what you're looking for,you can edit your css here then we can help

Answer (score 0):

```
.parent{
            position:absolute;
            left : 60px;
            top : 60px;
            width : auto;
            height:auto;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
        .parent .child{
            display:inline-block;
            border:1px solid blue;
        }

<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">aaaaaassssssssssssss</div>
    <div class="child">sssssssccccccccccccccccccc</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use a max-width to set a maximum width for the parent div so it doesn't get wider than specified.

Answer (score 0):

I did this easily.  Changing the width of the divs changes the parent as well.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1"></div>
    <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

<style>

div{border:1px solid black;}

.parent{

position:absolute;
width:auto;
height:auto;
}

.child1{
display:inline-block;
width:40px;
height:40px;
}

.child2{
display:inline-block;
width:30px;
height:40px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a responsive design, make sure you're using percentages, and not pixel values because the size of the divs will be calculated by the viewport width.

If you just want the parent to resize based on the **absolute** sizes of the child divs, add `height:auto; width:auto` to the parent. Then, change the child divs to `display:block; float:left`. The parent will resize accordingly.

## [Updated CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/mjGny)

**CSS**

```
.action_container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:auto;
}
.action_inner {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.action_inner {
    min-width: 120px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.action_title {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 3px;
}
.action_args_section {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.action_output_section {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
.parent{
  float: left;
  posetion: absolute;
background-color: yellow;
  width:auto;
  height: auto;
}
.parent div{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child1">this</div>
    <div class="child2">this</div>
</div>
```

Here's The Code You Need :)